# Delphi form naming conventions

Tags: delphi

I have read a lot of naming conventions for Delphi, but, even on a somewhat official documentation ([Object Pascal Style Guide](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/10280)), it seems to be no consensus as for form names.

Let's say I have a unit called "Main". According to the linked doc, the unit file name would be "Main.pas" and its class would be "TMain". But what about the form name (name property)? In my company, we usually name the forms with the prefix "F_" plus the unit name, in this example, "F_Main", but it feels weird when compared to the Embarcadero doc.

Is there a official convention, or a more used pattern?

Comment: Whatever works for you. We tend to name our units Mainform.pas (Mainform.dfm) and the object TfrmMain var frmMain. Some people name their units starting with a u like this: uMainform.pas and TFormMain.

Comment: We also use the f_ prefix (and Tf_ for the class). But the units also get a w_ prefix: Unit w_Main.pas / .dfm, form class Tf_Main, form variable f_Main (if used, we usually delete the default declaration). Elsewhere I have seen a Form suffix for the unit and a frm prefix: MainForm.pas / .dfm and TfrmMain / frmMain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no official naming convention in Delphi and you are free to use what best works for you, however there are good guidelines like the one I linked in my question. I personally decided to use "frm" since it matches my component naming prefixes, like "lbl" for labels as so on.